# Collection contents deleted when view is closed

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-relational

In my application, I have a `CompositeView` which wraps a cart-like object. When a user clicks an item, it is added to their cart, implemented like so:

```
// app.js:
app.main.show(new Cart({ collection: order.get('cart') });

...

// cart.js:
var Cart = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // Lots of configuration stuff
    addItemToCart: function() {
        this.collection.add(new Item());
        console.log(order.get('cart').length === 1); // true
    }
});

...

// back in app.js:
app.main.show(new SomeOtherView()); // closing out cart view
console.log(order.get('cart').length === 1); // false
```

However, even though my `order` object is persisted through the life of the `Cart` view, when I close the `Cart` view, the console logs out zero for `order.get('cart').length`. My `order` object is using the backbone-relational plugin to implement the relationship between the `order` object and the `cart` child collection, but even without it, this problem was occurring.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Maybe you could show the code before the call to `order.get('cart').length` when it is zero?

Comment: Good point. I've updated the code.

Comment: The life cycle of your cart view and the cart model should be totally separate. `Backbone.Relational` will destroy relations when you destroy the model but this should be independent of anything in your views. Do  you have other code that is managing the model life cycles?